# How do I determine an arbitrary C++ numeric type's real part's type?

Tags: c++, templates

Given an arbitrary numeric type which may or may not be a `std::complex` type, I'd like to get the type that represents the "real part" of that type.  For example, the real part of `std::complex<double>` is `double`, and the real part of `double` is `double` itself.  The example below uses C++ partial template specialization to accomplish this.  @mfontanini has posted an even simpler method below.

My question: is there a direct way of doing this that is already available in the Boost library?  If so, I have been unable to find it.

```
#include <complex>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_complex.hpp>

template <typename T>
class RealPart
{
private:
    template <bool, typename>
    class ResultType;

    // complex type -> real type
    template <typename T1>
    class ResultType<true, T1>
    {
    public:
        typedef typename T1::value_type type;
    };

    // real type -> real type
    template <typename T1>
    class ResultType<false, T1>
    {
    public:
        typedef T1 type;
    };

public:
    // define result_type, making use of the template specialization above
    typedef typename ResultType<boost::is_complex<T>::value, T>::type result_type;
};


// both will become doubles
RealPart<std::complex<double> > a;
RealPart<double> b;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use type traits, you can accomplish the same using only template specialization:

```
// general case
template <typename T>
struct RealPart {
    typedef T type;
};

// std::complex
template <typename T>
struct RealPart<std::complex<T> > {
    typedef T type;
};
```

Whether this is already implemented somewhere in boost, I don't really know.

Answer (score 2):

This works at compile-time:

```
// arr has type std::complex<T>
using RealType = decltype((*arr).real());

// or even
using RealType = decltype((U {}).real()); // U is std::complex<T>
```